# DevOps NugetCommand@2 - restoreSolution path

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

Within Azure DevOps, there's a [NugetCommand@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) that can build out MS .sln files for deployment.

On this command, the variable `restoreSolution` uses the example '**\*.sln'. If I have multiple .sln files in the same repository as the pipeline is running in, Microsoft does not state the proper way of navigating down towards to exactly the solution file I need.

I've tried methods such as:

```yaml
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Install NuGet packages'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'              # Options: restore, pack, push, custom
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'     # Required when command == Restore
        feedsToUse: 'config'            # Options: select, config - You can either select a feed from Azure Artifacts and or Nuget.org or commit a nuget.config file to source code 
        nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'   # Required when feedsToUse == Config - The NuGet.config in your repository that specifies the feeds from which to restore packages
        externalFeedCredentials: 'nuget-artifactory-$(System.TeamProject)'    # Optional - Credentials to use for external registries located in the selected NuGet.config. 
        restoreDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\s\Repository\FolderName\ProjectName'
```

Which builds out every solution in the Repository. Whereas this doesn't restore at all:

```yaml
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Install NuGet packages'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'              # Options: restore, pack, push, custom
        restoreSolution: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\s\Repository\FolderName\ProjectName\solution.sln'     # Required when command == Restore
        feedsToUse: 'config'            # Options: select, config - You can either select a feed from Azure Artifacts and or Nuget.org or commit a nuget.config file to source code 
        nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'   # Required when feedsToUse == Config - The NuGet.config in your repository that specifies the feeds from which to restore packages
        externalFeedCredentials: 'nuget-artifactory-$(System.TeamProject)'    # Optional - Credentials to use for external registries located in the selected NuGet.config.
```

Any suggestions to having the NugetCommand@2 package being able to point directly to a solution file when restoring and not a wildcard selector?

Comment: I'm not using Azure DevOps anymore, but did you try `dotnet restore` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore))?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming since this is a couple of months old you've resolved this issue but since no one answered...

First off - if you have a normal checkout, that is with no submodules - your repository name will not be in the path. So the second solution should work if you remove the Repository name from the path.

Having said that, the `restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'` starts its search for .sln files in the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) where the source code is checked out to and does equal "$(Pipeline.Workspace)\s"

You can also just put the name of the solution in the search. I'm assuming you're not going to have multiple solutions with the same name in your repo so you could just do this:

restoreSolution: '**\SolutionName.sln'

or give the relative path to the solution from the checked-out folder"

restoreSolution: '.\FolderName\ProjectName\solution.sln'

You may also have to give the path to the nuget.config unless it is at the root of your repo:

```
restoreSolution: '.\FolderName\ProjectName\solution.sln'
nugetConfigPath: '.\FolderName\ProjectName\nuget.config'
```

You can always query the build system by adding a PowerShell task to list the full path to all your solutions and knowing that the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) is up to the ..\s folder in the solution name:

```
  - powershell: |
      $solutions = (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.sln -Recurse).FullName
      foreach($solution in $solutions)
      {
       $solution
      }
   displayName: "List all Solutions"
```